# Why is my binary data bigger after getting it from the webserver?

Tags: java, python, django, file, byte

I need to serve a binary file through a web service implemented in Python/Django. The problem is, that when I compare the original file with the transferred file with *vbindiff* I see trailing bytes on the transferred file, sadly rendering it useless.

The Binary File is accessed saved by a client in Java with:

```
HttpURLConnection userdataConnection = null;
    URL userdataUrl = null;
    try {
        userdataUrl = new URL("http://localhost:8000/app/vuforia/10");

        userdataConnection = (HttpURLConnection) userdataUrl.openConnection();
        userdataConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        userdataConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        userdataConnection.connect();

        InputStream userdataStream = new BufferedInputStream(userdataConnection.getInputStream());
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream fileStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4094];
            while (userdataStream.read(buffer) != -1) {
                fileStream.write(buffer);
            }
            byte[] fileBytes = fileStream.toByteArray();
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("./test.dat")) {
                fos.write(fileBytes);
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I think that HttpURLConnection.getInputStream only reads the body of the response, or not?

This code serves the data in the backend

in views.py:

```
if request.method == "GET":
    all_data = VuforiaDatabase.objects.all()
    data = all_data.get(id=version)
    return FileResponse(data.get_dat_bytes())
```

in models.py:

```
def get_dat_bytes(self):
    return self.dat_upload.open()
```

How do I go about transferring the binary data 1:1?

Comment: Not the cause: a GET request has no request body, so don't set a content type for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re ignoring the return value of InputStream.read.

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D)):

> **Returns:**
>
> the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.

Your code is assuming that the buffer is filled with every call to `userdataStream.read(buffer)`, instead of checking how many bytes were actually read into `buffer`.

You don’t need to read from an InputStream at all.  Just use [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)):

```
Path file = Paths.get("./test.dat");

try (InputStream userdataStream = new BufferedInputStream(userdataConnection.getInputStream())) {
    Files.copy(userdataStream, file, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
}
```

Comment: This is a very elegant way to handle this task. Works like a charm. The files are now exactly the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You always write a multiple the 4094 bytes, no matter how many bytes you actually read.

Don't do `.write(buffer)`; [write the amount](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#write-byte:A-int-int-) you actually read. This is what `userdataStream.read` [returns you](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read-byte:A-). *It can return a number smaller than the buffer size,* but still positive.

If you project is using Apache Commons already, you can just use `copyInputStreamToFile`.

Note: 4K = 4096, not 4094, and it's a ridiculously small buffer, unless you operate something like a smartcard. On a PC, use something like a few hundred kb at least.

Comment: Thank you very much. This explanation helped alot!